# How to define menu item under Messagin menu in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

**Hello**,

I'm diving in Odoo through a book a bought called Odoo Development Essentials.
I'm trying to create a todo module.
By now i managed to create the module and installed it in the admin.

[image]

In the module, there are :

**openerp**.py

```
{
    'name': "Todo App",
    'description': "Long description of module's purpose",
    'author': "TSA",
    'depends': ['mail'],
    'application':True,
    'data': ['todo_view.xml'],
}
```

todo_model.py

```
from openerp import models, fields
class TodoTask(models.Model):
    _name = 'todo.task'
    name= fields.Char('Description',required=True)
    is_done = fields.Boolean('Done?')
    active = fields.Boolean('Active?',default=True)
```

**init**.py

```
from . import todo_model
```

todo_view.xml

```
<openerp>

<data>

    <!-- Action to open todo task list -->
    <act_window id="action_todo_task" name="Todo Task" res_model = "todo.task" view_mode="three,form"/>

    <!-- Menu item to open Todo task list -->
    <menuitem id="menu_todo_task" name="Todo Tasks" parent="mail.mail_feeds" sequence="20" action="action_todo_task"/>

</data>
```

The book says that, the menuitem with the parent mail.mail_feeds is used to add a menu item under the Messaging menu. Actually it does but when i try to click on the menu i have an error like this one:

[image]

I searched for hints on google but nothing found...
Can someone help me?

Thank you,
Thomas

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
parent="mail.mail_feeds"
```

with

```
parent="mail.mail_channel_menu_root_chat"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by inserting a record in **ir.ui.menu** . You can see a example something like that in addons/mail/mail_thread_view.xml in Odoo8 .

```
<record id="mail_inboxfeeds" model="ir.ui.menu">
  <field name="name">Inbox</field>
  <field name="sequence" eval="10"/>
  <field name="action" ref="action_mail_inbox_feeds"/>
  <field name="parent_id" ref="mail.mail_feeds"/>
</record>
```

you can also get the **action_mail_inbox_feeds** action definition in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

you also can copy the relevant code from v8 mail_thread_view.xml

insert into your todo_view.xml

```
      <!-- Top menu item -->
      <menuitem name="Messaging"
        id="mail.mail_feeds_main"
        groups="base.group_user"
        sequence="10"/>

      <!-- Left-side menu: Feeds -->
      <menuitem id="mail.mail_feeds"
        name="Messaging"
        parent="mail.mail_feeds_main"
        groups="base.group_user" sequence="10"/>
```

greetings Felipe